# Enviar dados da variável do JavaScript para o PHP

Tags: php, javascript, html5, front-end, back-end

Fiz um script em javascript que tem como objetivo gerar um número randômico e tomar uma decisão de acordo com o número selecionado:

```
var numero = Math.floor(3* Math.random());

switch (numero){
            case 0: 

            break
            case 1:
            break
            case 2: 
            break
```

Gostaria que, o resultado salvo na variável "numero" também fosse enviado para um código php, onde pegará o número sorteado e salvará ele dentro de um txt:

```
<?php


function gravar($texto){
    $arquivo = "relatorio.txt";
    $fp = fopen($arquivo, "a+");
    fwrite($fp, $texto);
    fclose($fp);
}

gravar($numero);


?>
```

Como posso fazer esse envio?

Comment: Você pode executar uma requisição ajax.

Comment: Nesse caso, como poderia utilizar o Ajax?

Comment: Importante você [edit] sua pergunta e explicar de maneira objetiva e pontual a dificuldade encontrada, acompanhada de um [mcve] do problema e tentativa de solução. Para entender que tipo de pergunta serve para o site e, consequentemente, evitar fechamentos e negativações vale a pena ler [O que é o Stack Overflow](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7256/70) e o [Guia de sobrevivência (resumido) do Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8089/70).

Answer (score -4, accepted):

Sua requisição Ajax pode ser feita da seguinte maneira:

Arquivo html:

```html
<html>
<head>
<!-- adiciona o jQuery -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-o88AwQnZB+VDvE9tvIXrMQaPlFFSUTR+nldQm1LuPXQ=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body>
<script>
/* define a variável "número" */
var numero = Math.floor(3* Math.random());
/* Implementa a requisição ajax */
$.ajax({

    url : 'seu-arquivo.php',
    type : 'POST',
    data : {
    /* adiciona a variavel com o número a requisicao*/
        'numero' : numero
    },
    dataType:'json',
    success : function(data) {              
        alert('Resultado: '+data);
    },
    error : function(request,error)
    {
        alert("Resultado: "+JSON.stringify(request));
    }
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

PHP:

```php
<?php 
$numero = (int)$_POST['numero'];
gravar($numero);
function gravar($texto){
    $arquivo = "relatorio.txt";
    $fp = fopen($arquivo, "a+");
    fwrite($fp, $texto);
    fclose($fp);
    echo json_encode("O número: {$texto} foi salvo");
}
?>
```

Caso não queira utilizar o jQuery, você pode tentar a resposta oferecida pelo @LordzSpectron

Comment: Olá, obrigado pela ajuda! Implementei o código, alterei o  url para o do meu arquivo, no entanto sempre é salvo no txt o número 0 (mesmo que eu volte pra página e gere outro randomicamente)

Comment: no arquivo do js aparece isso no console: Uncaught TypeError: $.ajax is not a function

Comment: adicionou o jQuery?

Comment: Sim, inclusive colei o código igual ao do exemplo

Comment: Corrigi a resposta. Eu havia adicionado o jQuery em sua versão slim, na qual não há mais suporte para $.ajax

Comment: Era isso mesmo, agora funcionou. Obrigado pela ajuda!

Comment: Se a resposta ajudou, por favor, considere aceitá-la como a resposta correta.

Comment: Marquei a resposta como correta!
Mais uma dúvida, os números estão sendo salvos todos juntos, como posso colocar um espaçamento entre eles? Exemplo: 1 2 0 3, como está: 1203

Comment: No lugar de usar `fwrite($fp, $texto);` tente `fwrite($fp, $texto . " ");`

Comment: Você também pode tentar: `fwrite($fp, $texto . PHP_EOL);`

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda novamente